# find non intersecting data set with linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<int> a = 1,2,3
List<int> b = 2,4,5

output
1,3,4,5
```

Comment: Should 3 also be in the output?

Comment: I'm guessing yes... that would be in the non-intersecting data.

Comment: This has a much better answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620266/the-opposite-of-intersect

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The trick is to use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) with the intersection of the two lists.

This should give you the list of non-intersecting elements:

```
var nonIntersecting = a.Union(b).Except(a.Intersect(b));
```

Comment: As I tested with a simple set it does not work. Though this solution works as stated by @Amicable in the original post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620266/the-opposite-of-intersect

Answer (score 4):

Tried and tested:

```
List<int> a = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3};
List<int> b = new List<int>(){2, 4, 5};


List<int> c = a.Except(b).Union(b.Except(a)).ToList();
```

Comment: i want to find the non intersecting part

Comment: Reed Copsey's answer is the better one!

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

```
List<int> a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> b = new List<int> { 2, 4, 5 };
var nonIntersecting = a.Union(b)
    .Where(x => !a.Contains(x) || !b.Contains(x));
```