# The opposite of Intersect()

Tags: c#, .net, collections, intersect

Intersect can be used to find matches between two collections, like so:

```
// Assign two arrays.
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] array2 = { 2, 3, 4 };
// Call Intersect extension method.
var intersect = array1.Intersect(array2);
// Write intersection to screen.
foreach (int value in intersect)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value); // Output: 2, 3
}
```

However what I'd like to achieve is the opposite, I'd like to list **items from one collection that are missing from the other**:

```
// Assign two arrays.
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] array2 = { 2, 3, 4 };
// Call "NonIntersect" extension method.
var intersect = array1.NonIntersect(array2); // I've made up the NonIntersect method
// Write intersection to screen.
foreach (int value in intersect)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value); // Output: 4
}
```

Comment: please confirm if you want 4 as the output, or 1 and 4

Comment: @oyvind-knobloch-brathen Yes, I would only like 4

Comment: As a side note, this type of set is called a [Symmetric Difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).

Comment: Technically speaking, a Symmetric Difference would result into [1, 4]. Since Peter wanted just the elements in array2 that are not in array1 (i.e., 4), that's called a [Relative Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) (aka Set-Theoretic Difference)

Answer (score 450, accepted):

As stated, if you want to get 4 as the result, you can do like this:

```
var nonintersect = array2.Except(array1);
```

If you want the real non-intersection (also both 1 and 4), then this should do the trick:

```
var nonintersect = array1.Except(array2).Union( array2.Except(array1));
```

This will not be the most performant solution, but for small lists it should work just fine.

Comment: You can probably do it faster by using two nested for loops, but the code will be way dirtier than this. Counting readability into this also, I would clearly use this variant as it's very easy to read.

Comment: Just a sideline point to add,
If you have:
 int[] before = { 1, 2, 3 };
 int[] after  = { 2, 3, 3, 4 };
and you try to use Except to find what's been added to 'after' since 'before':
 var diff = after.Except(before);
'diff' contains 4, not 3,4. i.e. watch out for duplicate elements giving you unexpected results

Comment: Would this perform better? 
array1.AddRange(array2.Except(array1));

Answer (score 96):

You can use

```
a.Except(b).Union(b.Except(a));
```

Or you can use

```
var difference = new HashSet(a);
difference.SymmetricExceptWith(b);
```

Comment: Interesting use of SymmetricExceptWith(), I wouldn't have thought of that approach

Comment: `SymmetricExceptWith` is probably my favourite method.

Comment: I compared the two in a real application where I had a couple lists of about 125 strings in each of them.  Using the first approach is actually faster for lists of that size, though its mostly insignificant as both approaches where under half a millisecond.

Comment: Would be nice if the BCL had a Linq extension method for this. It seems like an omission.

Comment: Someone benchmarked SymmetricExceptWith and found it much faster:
http://www.skylark-software.com/2011/07/linq-and-set-notation.html

Answer (score 13):

This code enumerates each sequence only once and uses `Select(x => x)` to hide the result to get a clean Linq-style extension method. Since it uses `HashSet<T>` its runtime is `O(n + m)` if the hashes are well distributed. Duplicate elements in either list are omitted.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SymmetricExcept<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq1,
    IEnumerable<T> seq2)
{
    HashSet<T> hashSet = new HashSet<T>(seq1);
    hashSet.SymmetricExceptWith(seq2);
    return hashSet.Select(x => x);
}
```

Comment: I like the extension method, but I'm not sure about the .Select(x => x). Don't you think it add some unnecessary overhead ?

Comment: Not sure the reason for the `hashSet.Select` but it seems that hashSet does implement IEnumerable anyway so it can just be used with `return hashSet;`

Answer (score 6):

I think you might be looking for `Except`:

> The Except operator produces the set
>   difference between two sequences. It
>   will only return elements in the first
>   sequence that don't appear in the
>   second. You can optionally provide
>   your own equality comparison function.

Check out [this link](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/ExceptOperator.ashx), [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx), or Google, for more information.

Answer (score 6):

array1.NonIntersect(array2);

Nonintersect such operator is not present in Linq you should do

except -> union -> except

```
a.except(b).union(b.Except(a));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what your NonIntersect method is supposed to do (regarding set theory) - is it
B \ A (everything from B that does not occur in A)?
If yes, then you should be able to use the Except operation (B.Except(A)).

Comment: Intersection of sets == A∪B\A∩B

Answer (score 2):

```
/// <summary>
/// Given two list, compare and extract differences
/// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620266/the-opposite-of-intersect
/// </summary>
public class CompareList
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns list of items that are in initial but not in final list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listA"></param>
    /// <param name="listB"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<string> NonIntersect(
        List<string> initial, List<string> final)
    {
        //subtracts the content of initial from final
        //assumes that final.length < initial.length
        return initial.Except(final);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the symmetric difference between the two list.
    /// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="initial"></param>
    /// <param name="final"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<string> SymmetricDifference(
        List<string> initial, List<string> final)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> setA = NonIntersect(final, initial);
        IEnumerable<string> setB = NonIntersect(initial, final);
        // sum and return the two set.
        return setA.Concat(setB);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string left = "411329_SOFT_MAC_GREEN";
string right= "SOFT_MAC_GREEN";

string[] l = left.Split('_');
string[] r = right.Split('_');

string[] distinctLeft = l.Distinct().ToArray();
string[] distinctRight = r.Distinct().ToArray();

var commonWord = l.Except(r, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
string result = String.Join("_",commonWord);
result = "411329"
```