# Comparing list against list, filtering/ignoring timestamp

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a program that validates the contents of file B (Potentially bad) against file A (Known good) and removes each known-good line from the potentially bad file and leaves only the potentially bad lines. The problem I am having is that each line contains a timestamp. How do I verify the contents of the line starting after the timestamp?

I.E. File A:

```
MSI (c) (74:80) [08:09:43:718]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (74:80) [08:09:43:718]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (74:80) [08:09:43:718]: ******* RunEngine:
```

Versus File B:

```
MSI (c) (E8:DC) [18:35:18:573]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (E8:DC) [18:35:18:573]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (E8:DC) [18:35:18:573]: ******* RunEngine:
```

These should all be considered equal.
I don't have an example of what is different but it will essentially be anything that is left once these are removed.

My code so far:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim compto As New List(Of String)
Dim compfrom As New List(Of String)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Standard("filea.LOG")
    Readfile("fileb.LOG")
    Writefile("difference.txt")
End Sub


Public Sub Standard(ByVal Path As String)
    Using r As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Path)
        Dim line As String = Nothing
        line = r.ReadLine
        Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
            line = r.ReadLine
            If Not compto.Contains(line) Then compto.Add(line)
        Loop
    End Using
End Sub

Public Sub Readfile(ByVal Path As String)
    Dim pattern As String = "{30}([A-Za-z0-9\-]+"
    Using r As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Path)
        Dim line As String = Nothing
        line = r.ReadLine
        Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
            line = r.ReadLine
            If Not compto.Contains(line) Then compfrom.Add(line)
        Loop
    End Using
End Sub

Public Sub Writefile(ByVal Path As String)
    Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Path)
        For Each line As String In compfrom
            sw.WriteLine(line)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(line)
        Next
    End Using
End Sub

End Class
```

So far, this code will remove exact matches but that is where I am stuck. Any help would be awesome.

Thanks.

Solution Edit:

```
Public Sub Writefile(ByVal Path As String)
    Dim GetLine As Func(Of String, String) = Function(line) Regex.Match(line, "\]: (.*)").Groups(1).Value
    Dim Diff As New HashSet(Of String)(File.ReadLines("filea.log").Select(GetLine))
    Diff.SymmetricExceptWith(File.ReadLines("fileb.log").Select(GetLine))
    Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Path)
        For Each line As String In Diff
            sw.WriteLine(String.Join("", line))
            ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Join("", line))
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post more samples of the files, showing a few lines that you consider identical, and a few that you consider different.

Comment: @MontyWild edited post due to formatting issues.

Comment: Could you edit your post; it's difficult to read these lines out of your comment.

Comment: How big are the files under discussion, and would it be practical to load them into memory for processing with LINQ?

Comment: @ZevSpitz 6,000+ lines and up to 10,000kb (so far, the code may later be adapted to larger files) I know nothing about LINQ but will research it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5620306/111794) link, try this:

```
Dim GetLine As Func(Of String,String) = Function(line) Regex.Match(line,"\]: (.*)").Groups(1).Value

'IF the timestamp is always at the same position, it may be more efficient to 
'avoid regular expressions. YMMV
GetLine = Function(line) line.Substring(32)

Dim Diff = New HashSet(File.ReadLines("filea.LOG").Select(GetLine))
Diff.SymmetricExceptWith(File.ReadLines("fileb.LOG").Select(GetLine))
```

Comment: That's probably a better overall solution than mine, but presuming that the line header is of constant length, you could get rif of the `Dim Getline`... line and substitute `File.ReadLines(` ... `).Select(getLine)` with `File.ReadLines(` ... `).Substring(32)` and not have to perform a slower `Regex` for each line.

Comment: @MontyWild If you mean that regular expressions are slower because they have to be recompiled each time, the static methods on `Regex` cache the compilation of the 15 (by default) last used regular expressions. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx).

Comment: @ZevSpitz Thanks! Added the code to op, seems to be functioning as desired.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you're comparing each unique line in `File A` to each line in `File B`, and that the line header `MSI (c) (74:80) [08:09:43:718]:` is irrelevant to this comparison, and that it is of constant length.

You might change your code (4 instances):

```
line = r.ReadLine
```

to:

```
line = r.ReadLine.Substring(32)
```

`Substring()` with one integer parameter returns the remainder of the string starting from the specified character position.

Comment: That would have worked except the documents contain the occasional blank or separation lines which create an exception due to string length being less than 32.