# Using IEnumerable.Except

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, except

I got 3 `listViews` 2 `textbox` and 2 `buttons` in WinForm.

Program Description: The program adds numbers to the `listview` by typing in numbers in the `textbox` and clicking the add `button`

Goal: I want to be able to use the `IEnumerable.Except` method to output only the unique numbers in `listView3`, for example in the picture below the unique numbers are 3 and 7 in `listView1` and `listView2`.
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(textBox1.Text);
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);

```
ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(textBox2.Text);
listView2.Items.Add(lv);

//im doing somthing wrong here...
var nonintersect = listView1.Except(listView2).Union(listView2.Except(listView1));

//populate listview3 with the unique numbers...
// foreach (item )
// {

// }
```

Error Message: System.Windows.Forms.ListView' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and no extension method 'Except' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

Comment: How about using the .Distinct extension method.

Comment: Please read [this](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2011/08/08/why-enumerableexcept-might-not-work-the-way-you-might-expect) famous blog to understand the internals of `Enumerable.Except()` method.

Answer (score 5):

It's called [Symmetric DIfference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) and it's simple as that.

```
var nonintersect = listView1.Except(listView2).Union(listView2.Except(listView1));
```

[Source Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620266/the-opposite-of-intersect)

Comment: Clever. I hand't though of an approach with `Union` yet.

Comment: How would i add this to my code? Can you provide the full code with array1 please. I'm still knew @OrelEraki

Comment: @BradleyDotNET,  Thanks, but it's Øyvind Bråthen answer, find it long time ago when i thought if there will be a nicer way of doing it.

Comment: When i copied and pasted it it gives me an error here: listView1.Except(listView2) and (listView2.Except(listView1)); @OrelEraki

Comment: @taji01 You need to be a lot more specific. You can't just post his line and say there is an error! Also, you need to be able to apply a concept in an answer to your code. We are here to provide answers, not do your work for you.

Comment: I'm sorry but i did try the problem myself for a couple of days now. I was trying to be clear, i only posted the lines where the red lines occurred. I'm still new to programming, but ill try to apply the concept. @BradleyDotNET

Comment: @taji01 Ok, but you didn't say what the error *was*, and there was only one line to start with, so pointing it seemed a bit... silly.

Comment: Sorry this was the Error: System.Windows.FormListView does not contain a definition for 'Except' and no extension method 'Except'
System.Windows.FormListView could be found (are you miss missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) @BradleyDotNET

Comment: @taji01 Ah, yes. You need to get the actual collection the list view holds (ie `Items`) and use that, not the listview itself (which is not an `IEnumerable`)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, I really don't know if i should write the lousy for loop that will populate the results he wants, or just letting him struggling it with himself. After all were not Code Factory.

Comment: @OrelEraki I think you answered the question. The title is even about `IEnumerable` (not `ListView`). The question of "How to turn this ListView into an `IEnumerable` of its contents is seperate (though trivial, just use `Select` or your for loop).

Comment: I would appreciate it if you did. I've been stuck trying to figure this out for a couple of days now and my last option was asking for help. @BradleyDotNET

Comment: @taji01 Considering there are now *two* hints on how to do this above, perhaps you should give it a go first? Do some Googling? Ask a seperate question when all that fails?

Comment: I'll keep trying. Hopefully ill get it by today, thanks for the hints guys. I appreciate it. @OrelEraki

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with *just* `Except`, as it would only return { 3 } or just { 7 } in your example. However, if you take the set *intersection* between the two { 1, 2, 4 } and then use `Except`, you can get the de-intersection (which is basically what you are looking for):

```
IEnumerable<int> allObjects = list1.Concat(list2);
IEnumerable<int> intersection = list1.Intersect(list2);
IEnumerable<int> deIntersection = allObjects.Except(intersection);
```

Comment: No need to do the `.Distinct()` the way `Execpt` processes it performs a distinct on the input list as it goes. The documentation specifically says it is the "Set Difference" so you can rely on this behavior.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for the note, I'll keep that in mind (and fixed the code).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> common =
        Enumerable
            .Intersect(
                listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(x => x.Text),
                listView2.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(x => x.Text));

IEnumerable<string> all =
        Enumerable
            .Union(
                listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(x => x.Text),
                listView2.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(x => x.Text));

IEnumerable<string> unique = all.Except(common);
```

Comment: He needs them for the same `ListViewItem` type in order to populate `listView3`, so why changing it into string ?

Comment: i copied and pasted it, it gave me no errors, but how do you populate the unique numbers to listView3? @Enigmativity

Comment: @OrelEraki - Do you know if `ListViewItem` properly implements equality by value?

Comment: @taji01 - Just like you would normally add text to a list view. Just do it in a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

`Except` is not defined for `ListView`.  It's actually an extension method that is defined in [System.Linq.Enumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx).  You're probably confused because you can call `Except` from `IList<T>` (since `IList<T>` derives from `IEnumerable<T>`), but what you're trying to do will never work because `ListView` doesn't inherit from `IEnumerable<T>`.  The exception you're getting is the correct behavior.

To get the `Except` behavior for your controls, you'll need to manipulate the underlying collection and then bind the resulting collection object to the `ListView` control.