# csharp compare lists<t> left to right and right to left

Tags: c#, list-comparison

from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693040.aspx list of strings can be compared  using the below code via linq. is there any built in way to compare list left to right and right to left?

```
class CompareLists
{        
    static void Main()
    {
        // Create the IEnumerable data sources.
        string[] names1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"../../../names1.txt");
        string[] names2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"../../../names2.txt");

        // Create the query. Note that method syntax must be used here.
        IEnumerable<string> differenceQuery =
          names1.Except(names2);

        // Execute the query.
        Console.WriteLine("The following lines are in names1.txt but not names2.txt");
        foreach (string s in differenceQuery)
            Console.WriteLine(s);

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

/* Output:
     The following lines are in names1.txt but not names2.txt
    Potra, Cristina
    Noriega, Fabricio
    Aw, Kam Foo
    Toyoshima, Tim
    Guy, Wey Yuan
    Garcia, Debra
     */

**Note: Left to Right means source list to destination list and vice versa.**

Comment: What would you expect that result set to look like?

Comment: Is this what you want? IEnumerable<string> differenceQuery =
          names1.Except(names2).Reverse();

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173762/check-if-two-lists-are-equal

Answer (score 2):

Consider [`Enumerable.Reverse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] names1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"../../../names1.txt")
                      .Reverse()
                      .ToArray();
```

Or, likely to be more efficient, to reverse the result, as **@JianpingLiu** suggested:

```
IEnumerable<string> differenceQuery = names1.Except(names2).Reverse();
```

Comment: IEnumerable<string> differenceQuery =
          names1.Except(names2).Reverse(); is better since differenceQuery is a subset of name1.

Comment: no matter how you sort the names1 and names 2, It makes no difference to the result.

Comment: @itsme86 Could be. What is your understanding of the question?

Comment: @AlexD I think they're interested in 2 separate results. One showing items in list1 that are missing in list2 and the second one that shows items in list2 that are missing in list1. I also think they're trying to get that data as one result set possibly? That's unclear, and the OP seems unwilling to answer my question about that.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want the text in `names2` but not in `names1`? If so try `names2.Except(names1)`

If you are looking for the everything outside the intersect of names1 and names2 check this answer [The opposite of Intersect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620266/the-opposite-of-intersect)

Comment: I am trying to see if list is of type (string, int and date time together). I am trying to compare source and destination lists and destination and source list s for differences.