# How to get missing items from two lists with different objects

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I'm trying and failing, actually, to get missing items from two lists, each list with his one type.

So, let's say I have two lists **`List<Game>`** and **`List<ValidGame>`** which contains all items that I should have in my app.

**LE:** Where properties Id and Name are the same on both lists.

```
public class Game {
   public Guid Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public List<Platform> Platforms {get; set;}
}

public class Platform {
   public Type PlatformType {get; set;}
   public string Version {get; set;}
}

public enum Type
{
     Unknown,
     iOS,
     Android
}
```

and ValidGame looks like this:

```
 public class ValidGame {
   public Guid Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
 }
```

How can I get the `ValidGames` that are not on the `List<Game>` but for each platform? Short story, I'm trying to find for each platform what game I'm missing.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: In which case a `ValidGame` and a `Game` are the same? When they have the same `Id`?

Comment: Please clarify what denotes your disjunctive union here; name, guid or something else?  Suggested reading: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5620266/125981

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes! Sorry that I didn't mentioned on the post. I'll update it now.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Thanks for pointing me out the Except method. Before asking this question, I had knowledge about this, but to use Except method you need both lists to have the same type.

Comment: Keep in mind that the "lists" can be the result of `.Select(same things)` from the original lists, either directly or to a new class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following lists:

```
List<ValidGame> validGames;
List<Game> games;
```

I would suggest something along the lines of:

1. For each `Game` object in `games`, creating a collection of 'platform and game ID' objects
   (resulting in one created object per `Platform` object in the `Game`'s `Platforms`)
2. Flattening the generated collections into one big collection
3. Grouping the 'platform and game ID' object collection by platform type and version
4. Creating a dictionary where the `Platform` object is the key, and a collection of the game IDs of the games that are already on that platform is the value
5. For each entry in the dictionary, evaluate which game IDs are missing

---

For a simple example (with simplified `GUID` values), let's say `games` contains two objects:

```
{
    Id: ABC
    Name: "GameA"
    Platforms:
    [
        { PlatformType: Android, Version: "V1" },
        { PlatformType: Android, Version: "V2" },
    ]
},
{
    Id: DEF
    Name: "GameB"
    Platforms:
    [
        { PlatformType: Android, Version: "V1" },
        { PlatformType: iOS, Version: "V1" },
    ]
},
```

The results of step 1--4 would look roughly like the following:

```
Result of step 1 + 2: Collection
--------------------------------
{ ( Platform: { PlatformType: Android, Version: "V1" }, GameId: ABC ) },
{ ( Platform: { PlatformType: Android, Version: "V2" }, GameId: ABC ) },
{ ( Platform: { PlatformType: Android, Version: "V1" }, GameId: DEF ) },
{ ( Platform: { PlatformType: iOS, Version: "V1" }, GameId: DEF ) },
```

```
Result of step 3: Grouping
--------------------------
{ Key: "Android_V1":
    { ( Platform: { PlatformType: Android, Version: "V1" }, GameId: ABC ) },
    { ( Platform: { PlatformType: Android, Version: "V1" }, GameId: DEF ) },
},
{ Key: "Android_V2":
    { ( Platform: { PlatformType: Android, Version: "V2" }, GameId: ABC ) },
},
{ Key: "iOS_V1":
    { ( Platform: { PlatformType: iOS, Version: "V1" }, GameId: DEF ) },
}
```

```
Result of step 4: Dictionary of game IDs already present on each platform
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    Key: { PlatformType: Android, Version: "V1" },
    Value: { ABC, DEF }
},
{
    Key: { PlatformType: Android, Version: "V2" },
    Value: { ABC }
},
{
    Key: { PlatformType: iOS, Version: "V1" },
    Value: { DEF }
},
```

---

Without having verified it in an IDE, the implementation of step 1--4 could be roughly as follows:

```
Dictionary<Platform, IEnumerable<Guid>> gameIdsPerPlatform = games
    // Step 1--2:
    .SelectMany(game => game.Platforms
        .Select(platform => (Platform: platform, GameId: game.Id)))
    // Step 3:
    .GroupBy(platformAndGameId =>
        $"{platformAndGameId.Platform.PlatformType}_{platformAndGameId.Platform.Version}")
    // Step 4:
    .ToDictionary(
        gr => gr.First().Platform,
        gr => gr.Select(platformAndGameId => platformAndGameId.GameId));
```

Here, several methods from the `System.Linq` namespace are used:

- [`.SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-7.0)
- [`.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-7.0)
- [`.GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-7.0)
- [`.ToDictionary()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-7.0)
- [`.First()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=net-7.0)

---

In step 5, [`.ExceptBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.exceptby?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-exceptby-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1))-system-func((-0-1)))) (also from the `System.Linq` namespace) may be used to find which games are **missing** from each platform:

```
Dictionary<Platform, List<ValidGame>> missingGamesPerPlatform = gameIdsPerPlatform
    .ToDictionary(
        kvp => kvp.Key,
        kvp => validGames
            .ExceptBy(kvp.Value.Select(game => game.Id), validGame => validGame.Id)
            .ToList()
    );
```

---

**Note:**
This suggested approach assumes that the uniqueness of a game (whether it's an existing game or a valid game) is defined by the `Game`'s/`ValidGame`'s `Id` value (i.e. if two `Game`/`ValidGame` objects have identical `Name` values, they will also have identical `Id` values). If that is a wrong assumption, changes need to be made for this approach to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I used some parts of you solution. So, on the List<ValidGame> I added also the PlatformType foreach item of this list. Then, flattening the List<Game> and mapping  it to another list of type List<ValidGame>. Then I did an Except on those lists and voila :). It worked like a charm. Thank you again!

Comment: Great to hear that you found a solution that works for you! Glad to be able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your code makes this very difficult, and this would be much easier if each platform had a list of Games, instead of each Game having a list of platforms. However, with the way your code is set up, I'll show you how.

First, in platform, let's override the `.Equals()` method that all objects inherit, as well as `.GetHashCode()`

```
public class Platform 
{
    public Type PlatformType { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    
    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        if ((obj == null) || ! this.GetType().Equals(obj.GetType()))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return (this.PlatformType == obj.PlatformType)
                && (this.Version == obj.Version)
        }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (int)PlatformType;
    }
}
```

This makes comparing two platforms much simpler.

Also make an override of `Equals` for `Game`, where the name and the id are the same, and `GetHashCode` where it returns the game ID.

Now, we are going to create a `List<Platform>` so we can get the desired result

```
List<Game> games; // You already have this, I'm just giving it a name.
List<ValidGame> validGames; // You already have this, I'm just giving it a name.

if (!games.Any())
{
    // This is just an example. Add whatever handling you would like here
    throw new Exception("The list of games is null");
}

List<Platform> platforms = new()
{
    games.First()
};

for (int i = 0; i < games.Count; i++)
{
    int platformIndex = -1;

    foreach (Platform platform in platforms)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < games[i].Platforms.Count; j++)
        {
            if (platform.Equals(games[i].Platforms[j]))
                platformIndex = j;
        }
    }

    if (platformIndex > -1)
    {
        platforms.Add(games[i].Platforms[platformIndex]);
    }
}
```

The above code creates a non duplicating list of all of the platforms.

With that information, let's create a new `List<List<Game>>`, the nested list is so we can keep every platform's games separate. The following code continues the above code.

```
List<List<Game>> gamesInPlatforms = new();

// This will create a list of lists, where the size is based
// on the amount of unique platforms there are.
for (int i = 0; i < platforms.Count; i++)
{
    gamesByPlatforms.Add(new List<Game>());
}

Console.WriteLine("The following valid games are found in no platforms: ");

foreach (ValidGame validGame in validGames)
{
    bool isValidGameFound = false;

    foreach (Game game in games)
    {
        if (game.Equals(ToGame(validGame)))
            isValidGameFound = true;
    }

    if (!isValidGameFound)
        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {validGame.Name}, ID: {validGame.Id}");
}

// This will sort the games into their respective lists
for (int i = 0; i < platforms.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (Game game in games)
    {
        foreach (Platform gamePlatform in game.Platforms)
        {
            if (platforms[i].Equals(gamePlatform))
                gamesByPlatforms[i].Add(game);
        }
    }
}

//This final bit will output the games not found based on platform type
for (int i = 0; i < platforms.Count; i++)
{
    bool isFirstGame = true;
    foreach (ValidGame validGame in validGames)
    {
        if (!gamesByPlatforms[i].Contains(ToGame(validGame)))
        {
            if (isFirstGame)
            {
                isFirstGame = false;
                Console.WriteLine($"Platform, Platform Type: {platforms[i].PlatformType.ToString()} Platform Version: {platforms[i].Version} does not contain the following valid games:");
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {validGame.Name}, ID: {validGame.Id}");
        }
    }
}

Game ToGame(ValidGame validGame)
{
    Game game = new();
    game.Id = validGame.Id;
    game.Name = validGame.Name;
}
```

That's it. Now you can see in the console which valid games aren't found in each platform. Hope this helps!